# What does "replacing" mean in Tortoise SVN changelog?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Once in a while I see that a file is listed in a commit in Tortose SVN changelog and the "action" column reads "replacing".

What does that mean? How is that different from "modified"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html), replacing is different from modified in the following way.

```
Item has been replaced in your working copy. This means the file was scheduled 
for deletion, and then a new file with the same name was scheduled for addition 
in its place.
```

Comment: Does this have any implications besides showing the action history of the version control managers?

Comment: Yes. If it's being added *with history* i.e. via a copy or rename, then doing a "show log" on the item will follow the history of whatever it was copied or renamed from rather than the history on whatever file it was replacing.